# symfony2 error, stty not recognized

Tags: symfony, stty

I am following [the tutorial](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/27/symfony2-jobeet-day-3-the-data-model/). When I am using the command

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

then I am getting an error

```
C:\wamp\www\Symfony>php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
'stty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

  [RuntimeException]

  The autoloader expected class "Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineF
ixturesBundle" to be defined in file "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app/../vendor/bundles\
Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle.php". The file was
found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a ty
po.
```

I am new to symfony2.

Comment: What version of Symfony2 are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I notice is that you don't use the correct namespace of the `DoctrineFixturesBundle`. I suggest you to update the library.

> **WARNING: Namespace changed**
>
> This bundle was previously under the `Symfony\Bundle` namespace and is now moved to the `Doctrine\Bundle` namespace.

Secondly, you need to declare the `DoctrineFixturesBundle` inside your `AppKernel`.

```php
// ...
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        // Be carefull with the namespace!
        new \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        // ...
    );
    // ...
}
```

You can find further information here: [`DoctrineFixturesBundles`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) (not up to date!)